# cropping image by black pixel threshold

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I have an image like this

[image]

In the upper part of the image there is some irrelevant space I want to crop. I marked it here:

[image]

The amount of black pixels in the first few lines is roughly the same.

So my idea is to loop through the rows of this image, starting from the top (row 0) and then check if row+10 has the same amount of black pixels.

If yes, go on, if no, this is the break point.

However, I cannot get this to work. Here is my code

```
for i in range(img.shape[0]):
    low = sum(np.bincount(img[i,:])[0:5]) # number of black pixels
    high = sum(np.bincount(img[i+10,:])[0:5]) #number of black pixels in row i+10
    #print(i)
    if(low-low*0.01 < high):
        print(i)
        break
```

then crop image:

```
imcrop = img[int(0+i):,:]
```

with `np.bincount` I sum the number of the five darkest pixels (0=black, 255=white)

and then loop until I find the break point.

By experimenting with the threshold levels, I found that it either outputs 0 or a number that is way too high.

What would be a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> Quite slow but works. At first move along left to right to find boundary between black pixels and other pixels. After that move from right to left to find boundary between black and other pixels. Finally we get two list of boundary as left_data and right_data.
>   From first row check distance between left boundary to right boundary and move until distance is same then stop. Finally we get four corner of desired image.

```
import cv2

image =  cv2.imread('sample.png') #Test Image
image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

height = image.shape[0]
width = image.shape[1]

Black = 0
left = 0
right = 0

data_left = [] #left boundary
data_right = [] #right boundary
for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width-1):
        first = image[i][j]
        second = image[i][j+1]
        if(first==Black and second!=Black):
            left=j
    data_left.append(left)

for i in range(height):
    j = width-1
    found = 0
    while(found==0 and j>=0):
        first = image[i][j]
        second = image[i][j-1]
        if(first==Black and second != Black):
            right = j
            found = 1
        j = j-1
    data_right.append(right)        
left_start = [0,data_left[0]]
right_start = [0,data_right[0]]
left_end = 0
right_end = 0

i = 0
found = 0
while(i<len(data_left) and found == 0):
    if((data_left[i]==left_start[1] and data_right[i]==right_start[1])==False):
        found = 1
        left_end = [i,data_left[i]]
        right_end = [i,data_right[i]]
    i = i+1 

width = data_right[0]-data_left[0]
height = left_end[0]
pos_y = 0
pos_x = data_left[0]
crop_image = image[pos_y:pos_y+height, pos_x:pos_x+width]
cv2.imwrite('result.jpg',crop_image) # result image
```

> **Original Image**

[image]

> **Result Image**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To crop an Image in openCV

```
crop_img = img[200:400, 100:300]
```

where 100 and 300 are the width and height of the image crop, 200 and 400 are the top left co-ordinates of the image crop.